# Schedule a trigger for a job that is excecuted on every node in a cluster

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I'm wondering if there is a simple workaround/hack for quartz of triggering a job that is excecuted on every node in a cluster.

My situation:
My application is caching some things and is running in a cluster with no distributed-cache. Now I have situations where I want to refresh the caches on all nodes triggered by a job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have found out, Quartz always picks up a random instance to execute a scheduled job and this cannot be easily changed unless you want to hack its internals.

Probably the easiest way to achieve what you describe would be to implement some sort of a coordinator (or master) job that will be aware of all Quartz instances in the cluster and will "manually" trigger execution of the cache-sync job on every single node. The master job can easily do it via the RMI, or JMX APIs exposed by Quartz.

You may want to check this somewhat [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665688/quartz-scheduler-trigger-some-jobs-on-every-cluster-node-and-some-only-once-per/23673652#23673652).