# Quartz Job/Trigger listeners on clustered environment, Listening every node how?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cluster-computing, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I have built a project using Quartz with a clustered environment.
And when an unelected node reaches CronTrigger, I want to make a certain logic run.
However, JobListener/TriggerListener in Quartz only listens on the elected node. Is there a way to get logic running on all nodes?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with quartz described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23673652/175554). But you can use spring **@Scheduled**

In any config bean define the annotation like below **@EnableScheduling**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SpringConfig {
    ...
}
```

And choose any function to run in cron, and define like below

```java
@Scheduled(cron = "0 15 10 15 * ?")
public void scheduleTaskUsingCronExpression() { 
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
    System.out.println(
      "schedule tasks using cron jobs - " + now);
}
```

or for fixed delay

```java
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
public void scheduleFixedDelayTask() {
    System.out.println(
      "Fixed delay task - " + System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
}
```

Reference: https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/